# ng-model Not Updating from jQuery Slider

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ngmodel

My HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">                    
    <div id='slider-children'></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.one">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.second">
 </div>
```

The Angular part:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myController',myController);
 function myController() {
    var self=this;
    $("#slider-children").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 99,
        range:true,
        values: [10, 20],
        change: function ( event, ui ) {
            self.one=ui.values[0];
            self.second=ui.values[1];
            console.log(self.one);
            console.log(self.second);
        }
        });     
 }
```

Could someone explain to me why the input texts `do not upgrade` while I slide the jQuery UI slider whereas **ctrl.one** and **ctrl.second** have the right values? They do upgrade only sometimes! *What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Mixing AngularJS and jQuery can be tricky. Because the slider events come from outside the AngularJS framework, the `ng-model` needs to be updated with `$setViewValue`, for more information, see [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference -- setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue)

Comment: If you could give me a hand, I'd be grateful. I made some efforts but I cannot make it work...

Comment: Google "angular slider demo". There are plenty of working examples.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot utilize the full JQuery features inside the angular.

there are two alternative solutions

1.You can assign the values into text box from jquery, and just past the following code into your html page. it will automatically bind the values from text box to angular module, when we update the values throught javascript / jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        !function (n, t) { "use strict"; var r = n.fn.val; n.fn.val = function (n) { if (!arguments.length) return r.call(this); var e = r.call(this, n); return t.element(this[0]).triggerHandler("input"), e } }(window.jQuery, window.angular);
    </script>
```

2.You can use Angular slide instead of Jquery like
http://angular-slider.github.io/angularjs-slider/